# Python finding 'keys'

Tags: python

Hey I am having some difficulty finding the keys: "ace" and "two" here. I get the error that 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'. Can someone help?

```
cards = [{"ace": 11},{"two": 2}]
for items in cards:
  def list_keys(items):
    return items.keys()

keys = list_keys(cards)
print(keys)
```

Comment: `cards` is a list of dictionaries. Did you want a single dictionary `cards = {"ace": 11, "two": 2}`?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, this is very strange. What do you expect at the end ? A list with the keys, a unique dictionnary  ?

Comment: Fixed it! First question on stackflow, thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you declaring a method under `for` loop? Do you mean to call the function under `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is making a list filled with dictionaries. Instead you just want a single dictionary:

```
cards = {"ace": 11, "two": 2}
```

The outcome of the for loop is to define the function length of cards times, which doesn't make sense.
You should put it at the start to make sure it's defined and only once.

If you want just the keys you can do this:

```
keys = cards.keys()
```

Or put it inside your function:

```
def list_keys(items):
    return items.keys()
keys = list_keys(cards)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the `cards` variable is a List. In order to get the `keys()`, you need to go inside the list and then use the keys() function

```py
cards = [{"ace": 11},{"two": 2}]

def list_keys(items):
    return items.keys()

for items in cards:
  keys = list_keys(items)
  print(keys)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation! :)

Comment: Please consider upvoting or approving the answer if this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
list_list = [list(x.keys()) for x in cards]
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
res = flatten(list_list)
print(res)
#['ace', 'two']
```